# Can I write both copy and move assignment operators for a class?

Tags: c++, move-semantics, copy-assignment

These are my prototypes,

```
MyClass& operator=(MyClass rhs);   // copy assignment
MyClass& operator=(MyClass &&rhs); // move assignment
```

But when I call

```
MyClass a, b;
a = std::move(b);
```

, there is an error.

```
556 IntelliSense: more than one operator "=" matches these operands:
        function "MyClass::operator=(MyClass rhs)"
        function "MyClass::operator=(MyClass &&rhs)"
        operand types are: MyClass = MyClass
```

And the compiler returns:

```
Error   56  error C2593: 'operator =' is ambiguous
```

Comment: IntelliSense errors are not always real compiler errors.

Comment: Try changing the copy-assignment operator to take a *reference*, preferably a constant reference.

Comment: An rvalue of type `MyClass` binds to both functions equally well. This is indeed ambiguous.

Comment: Copy assignment conventionally takes `MyClass const & rhs`

Answer (score 11):

Overload resolution is ambiguous because when you pass an rvalue, both `MyClass` and `MyClass &&` can be directly initialised by it.

If you want to provide a different implementation of copy and move assignment, the customary way is to take the copy assignment operator's parameter by const reference:

```
MyClass& operator=(const MyClass &rhs);   // copy assignment
MyClass& operator=(MyClass &&rhs); // move assignment
```

Done like this, the move assignment operator is a strictly better match for a (non-const) rvalue argument and so it's chosen by overload resolution.

An alternative approach, called copy-and-swap, is to provide just the assignment operator, take the parameter by value, and use `swap` to implement it:

```
MyClass& operator=(MyClass rhs)
{
  swap(*this, rhs);
  return *this;
};
```

This reuses the copy/move constructor for the assignment. It requires you to have implemented a `swap` function, which should be non-throwing.

The downside of this approach is that sometimes, manually implementing copy assignment can be cheaper than performing copy construction followed by a move.

Comment: My copy assignment operator is implemented exactly as yours. Does it mean, in that way, MyClass& operator=(MyClass rhs) is both a copy and a move assignment operator?

Comment: @ZHOU Formally speaking, no, it's a copy assignment operator only. But assuming that you have a move constructor, it can be expected that for rvlaues, the copy-and-swap assignment operator will be as efficient as a move assignment operator would be.